# PC crashes while running graphically demanding software

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, crash

Recently I've ran into some problems with my PC. Everytime I play the game Rainbow Six Siege, after loading into a match for a few seconds my PC would crash.

The symptoms of the crashes would be vertical lines, usually grey, other times the dominant color on the screen at the time of the crash, sound would go on for a few more seconds then it would become distorted and the whole system stops repsonding entirely After that the PC won't boot until I've removed the RAM sticks and the GPU out and put them in again several times; all the lights would light up but there is nothing on the screen.

At first I figured this would be a RAM problem because I've run into something similar before, but then I switched the RAM and the problem would persist. Then thinking the game itself is causing me problems I ran several other intensive games to test, these would take longer but eventually I'd run into the same problems.

At the moments I'm leaning on a defective GPU, but there's a chance it would be the motherboard. Any input to pinpoint the exact issue I'd appreciate it a lot. Hope y'all have had a merry Christmas, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Could also be power or temperature  related. Use Coretemp to measure CPU temperature and GPU-z to monitor graphics card temperatures.

Comment: @Mokubai everything is fine, the CPU never goes past 70 Celsius and the GPU would never go past 80. Also I clean my computer at least twice a month and reapply the thermal paste every 6 month.

I've also switched out the old PSU with a new one, nothing improved.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like a hardware issue; I've seen this happen if the GPU is overheating (possibly due to a fan getting stuck), and something similar if my CPU/GPU/RAM overclock is higher than stable levels.

(Note: I don't believe you're supposed to reapply thermal paste like that.)

Comment: The thing is I've only run the game for like 3 minutes. It's impossible for the whole system to get hot enough to crash like that. I've checked and under load all three fans work normally.